# My laptop starts heating when I train models on Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

My laptop starts heating when I train models on Google Colaboratory. I clearly hear that my coolers make noise. Is it okay? How do I stop it? As I understand, I run models in cloud, not on my lapton, at least I didn't change default settings